# wordpress xmlrpc: not decoding utf-8

Tags: wordpress, encoding, xml-rpc

I'm using wordpress xmlrpc to create a new post(wp.newpost) .but i have problem with encoding .what sort of encoding should i use?when the post is created persian caracters are utf-8 encoded and wordpress do not decode them (but english caracters are ok).
below is an example of a persian word that is utf-8 encoded after that xmlrpc creates a post .
ÙÛÙÙ ÙØ§

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved by using
`array('encoding'=>'UTF-8','escaping'=>'markup')`
as an optional parameter for xmlrpc_encode_request function